# Could super-cold LOX be used in every rocket engine?

Tags: fuel, engine-design, liquid-fuel, lox, sub-cooled

Super-cold LOX gives advantages in performance for a rocket. But it isn't used in all rockets. SpaceX's Merlin 1D rocket engine uses super-cold LOX. Also NK-33 use sub-cooled LOX. Could super-cold LOX be used in every rocket engine? Does it needs modification with new parts or does it need a new design of the entire engine?

Comment: It'd take a fundamental redesign for use in the [Space Shuttle SRB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Solid_Rocket_Booster). ;)

Comment: Is there meant to be a distinction here between "subcooled" and "super-cold"? Subcooled seems to be an actual term used in spaceflight.

Comment: When Space-X talks about supercooled oxygen they mean it is just a few degrees above it's freezing point, as opposed to common LOX that is just under it's boiling point.

Comment: Afaik there is a difference between super-cold and supercooled, the latter being a term with specific definition of "under the freezing temperature but still not frozen"

Comment: If the density of the super-cold LOX is substantially larger than that of boiling LOX, modification of turbopumps and injectors might be necessary. Keeping the LOX cold before and shortly after the launch might be a problem. A launch delay should not destroy the tanks by expanding LOX.

Comment: @Uwe while true that such modifications might be needed, the turbopumps for super-cold oxygen would likely be actually *easier* than for normal LOX; higher density is not as much problem (until we're dealing with slurries and thicker) as raw flow rate, turbopumps operating at lower RPM and taking less stress moving the same (molar) amount of oxygen. Injectors might need modifications but neither harder nor easier than normally. The biggest challenge would be an audit of all materials used and their performance in lower temperature.

Comment: @uwe's point is good that there are operational challenges. Spacex needs to fuel the vehicle while the crew is onboard because of their use of subcooled LOX; this is counter to all NASA practice and is causing trouble.

Comment: SpaceX is misusing the term 'supercooled' (as @jkavalik says, that means the liquid is below freezing point). Subcooled is the correct term.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No, lots of them don't use oxygen at any temperature or density

Long answer:
Less no. If you take an engine that uses liquid oxygen and put subcooled liquid oxygen into it, it will be subject to additional thermal stresses and the turbopumps involved will be pumping a liquid denser than they were designed for. If neither of those problems destroy it or prevent it from starting, it will work but the turbopumps will almost certainly not be delivering the oxygen at the correct rate because of the increased density.

Comment: If the mixture gets too oxygen rich by using subcooled LOX, damages by excess oxidation of combustion chamber and nozzle are possible.

Comment: Good point. Hadn't thought of that one.